# module 'plotnine' has no attribute 'ggplot_build'

Tags: python, python-ggplot, plotnine

p3 = (p9.ggplot(data = df, mapping = p9.aes(x = 'gross_power', y = 'temp_drop_a',show_legend=False, alpha = 0.7))
+ p9.geom_jitter()
+ p9.geom_smooth(se= 'F',method="lm", colour = 'red'))

mygg_data = p9.ggplot_build(p3).data[[2]]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.  There is no "ggplot_build".  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ggplot_build` in `plotnine` and it is not needed.  I assume you are trying to plot a regression line.  An example is below.

Also `se= 'F'` will not work.  If you do not want to display confidence intervals, it is `se= False`.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import mpg as df

df = df[df['cyl']!=5]

def regline(cyl):
    data = df[df['cyl']==cyl]    
    params = stats.linregress(data['displ'],data['hwy'])
    if params[0] < 0:
        return 'y = {:.4f} - {:.4f} x'.format(params[1],abs(params[0]))
    else:
        return 'y = {:.4f} + {:.4f} x'.format(params[1],params[0])

regline4 = regline(4)
regline6 = regline(6)
regline8 = regline(8)


p = (ggplot(df, aes(x='displ', y='hwy',color='factor(cyl)'))
  + theme_light(8)
  + geom_jitter(size=0.8, alpha=0.4)
  + geom_smooth(aes(fill='factor(cyl)'),method='lm',alpha=0.3)
  + annotate('text', label=regline4, x=2.05, y=33.5, size=7, color='#005D17', ha='left')
  + annotate('text', label=regline6, x=3.95, y=28, size=7, color='#7E191B', ha='left')  
  + annotate('text', label=regline8, x=6.5, y=21.5, size=7, color='#1C2E4A')
  + labs(x='Displacement', y='Miles per gallon (highway)')
  + scale_color_manual(('#005D17','#7E191B','#1C2E4A'))
  + scale_fill_manual(('#50C878','#E78587','#89CFF0'))
  + theme(
      legend_title=element_blank(),
      legend_key=element_rect(color='white'),
      legend_direction='horizontal',
      legend_position='bottom',
      legend_box_spacing=0.25,
      legend_background=element_blank(),
 )
)
p
```

[image]